# Get applications package name

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, package, xamarin

I am using Xamarin. I need to get the Google Maps API key and to do this I need my application's package name. How do I get this?

My app is called SimpleMapDemo and is one of the samples for using Google Maps.

Comment: check your manifest file for package name

Comment: http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAndroid.Content.Context.PackageName see the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your Manifest file and you shall find the package name of your application from the `<manifest>` tag.

Below is an example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.recorder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

In the above example my applications package name is: `com.example.recorder`