# Xamarin Cross Platform Application Package Name in C#

Tags: xamarin

Is there a way to programmatically access the application package name/namespace/version information in Xamarin portable C# code?

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643221/android-how-to-get-package-name) (link is how to access for Android, I want to know if there is a pre-existing C# cross platform way to access this in the portable class code.)

Not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876576/get-applications-package-name).

Comment: There is no method in Xamarin.Forms but if you want you can create a dependency service to get the package name from respective platforms.

Comment: Oh well.  I was hoping to avoid that.  I'll post the solution here when done (for iOS and Android).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

i got answer to your problem, but it is using dependency service to work. There is no other way if there is no Xamarin plugin.
Here is the code:

Interface in pcl project:

```
public interface IPackageName
{
    string PackageName { get; }
}
```

Android implementation:

```
public class PackageNameDroid : IPackageName
{
    public PackageNameDroid()
    {
    }

    public string PackageName
    {
        get { return Application.Context.PackageName; }
    }
}
```

iOS implementation:

```
public class PackageNameIOS : IPackageName
{

    public PackageNameIOS()
    {
    }

    public string PackageName
    {
        get { return NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleIdentifier; }
    }

}
```

Don't forget to mark platform files for dependency service in Android file:

`[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PackageNameDroid))]`

and iOS file:

`[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PackageNameIOS))]`

Now you're good to go and can use it in PCLs just like that:

`string packageName = DependencyService.Get<IPackageName>().PackageName;`

Hope it helps others.